# EF add List of entites to an existing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having an issue trying to add a list of entities to an existing entity.

Example -

My object Trade has a List offered and a List selected

When a trade is first created it contains a list of offered items.  When someones selects items from the offered they are to be saved in the Selected field.

in my save i did the following

```
internal void acceptTrade(Trade trade)
{
   using(var context = new datacontext())
   {
    Context.Entry(Trade).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Trade.Status = "Accepted";
    Foreach(selected)
    {
       Context.entry(selected).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();

  }
 }
```

However, with this i get the following error

Attaching an entity of type item failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'unchanged' or 'modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values.  This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new

Ive tried to set each of the offered state to unchanged

```
internal void acceptTrade(Trade trade)
{
    Context.Entry(Trade).State = EntityState.Modified;
    Trade.Status = "Accepted";
    Foreach(selected)
    {
       Context.entry(selected).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    foreach(offered)
    {
       Context.Entry(offered).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

and i still get the same error.

I even tried to use migrations by doing

```
 db.set<Trade>().AddorUpdate(trade);
```

and no error occured but nothing was saved or modified.

Comment: Are you keeping the context alive? Were these Trade objects loaded from the same Context instance?

Comment: No the TradeObject was loaded from a previous database call.  In the controller I then take the Existing Trade object and Add the selected items to the Trade object and pass the Entire Trade object into the AcceptTrade Call.  So its a new context of an existing object

Comment: What the error is essentially saying is that you are trying to attach an entity when one already exists with the same key. I think you loaded a Trade entity with the same id in that context and now you are trying to attach another one with the same id from another context.